# How do I create a package that contains pictures that copy themselves directly to the "Backgrounds" folder?

Tags: 11.10

How do I create a package that contains pictures that copy themselves directly to the "Backgrounds" folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backgrounds are stored in `/usr/share/backgrounds/`

There is a packaging guide on:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Basic

Comment: Every time I got to copy something to the Backgrounds folder, it denies me access to.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at other artwork packages.

To do so, use apt-get source PACKAGE

Then it should show you how it puts the backgrounds into the backgrounds folder.

For example: apt-get source blubuntu-look

You will need dpkg-dev installed, but this should hopefully provide you with enough information to get a wallpaper package built.